# Defining custom error handlers for certain domain patterns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, uwsgi, flask-restful

I'm working with Flask and am wondering if it's possible to customize error pages based on a domain pattern.

For example, the default error page is an HTML response with something like "404: Not Found". I'm setting up a REST-like API for a subdomain `api.localhost:5000`. What I'd like to do is to somehow tell Flask that if you see a domain such as `api.localhost:5000/*` and you receive a 404, send back a jsonified response, otherwise go ahead and send back an HTML response.

Here's a simple example:

```py
from flask import abort, jsonify, Blueprint
api = Blueprint("api", __name__)

@api.route("/bad/route", subdomain="api")
def api_base():
    """Purposefly define a bad route and send back jsonified error response."""
    # Forcefully calling `abort` will generate a jsonified response
    abort(404)
    # However, if I didn't anticipate a bad path and didn't call `abort`, a
    # default HTML 404 page is returned, which is defined in the `error`
    # blueprint located elsewhere in the application.

@api.errorhandler(404)
def resource_not_found(e):
    return jsonify(error=str(e)), 404
```

So if I made the request:

```
http://api.localhost:5000/bad/route
```

I'd get a nice json response, otherwise something like `http://api.localhost:5000/another/bad/route` will return a 404 HTML response.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom flask class with your own process_response

working example:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, abort, jsonify, Blueprint, jsonify, make_response

api = Blueprint("api", __name__)

@api.route("/good")
def good_route():
    return app.make_response("Hello World")

@api.route("/bad/route")
def api_base():
    """Purposefly define a bad route and send back jsonified error response."""
    # Forcefully calling `abort` will generate a jsonified response
    abort(404)
    # However, if I didn't anticipate a bad path and didn't call `abort`, a
    # default HTML 404 page is returned, which is defined in the `error`
    # blueprint located elsewhere in the application.

@api.errorhandler(404)
def resource_not_found(e):
    return jsonify(error=str(e)), 404


class MyFlask(Flask):
    def process_response(self, response):
        #Every response will be processed here first
        if response.status_code == 404:
            # send a json response
            return make_response(jsonify({"error": "Route Not found"}), 404)
        return response

app = MyFlask("api")
app.register_blueprint(api)
```

Testing it:

```
(venv) bhakta@blr:~/dev/flask$ curl -D headers -X GET http://api.localhost:5000/good
Hello World(venv) bhakta@blr:~/dev/flask$
(venv) bhakta@blr:~/dev/flask$
(venv) bhakta@blr:~/dev/flask$
(venv) bhakta@blr:~/dev/flask$ cat headers
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 11
Server: Werkzeug/0.15.0 Python/3.6.8
Date: Sun, 01 Aug 2021 10:35:38 GMT

(venv) bhakta@blr:~/dev/flask$
(venv) bhakta@blr:~/dev/flask$
(venv) bhakta@blr:~/dev/flask$
```

```
(venv) bhakta@blr:~/dev/flask$ curl -D headers -X GET http://api.localhost:5000/bad
{"error":"Route Not found"}
(venv) bhakta@blr:~/dev/flask$
(venv) bhakta@blr:~/dev/flask$
(venv) bhakta@blr:~/dev/flask$ cat headers
HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 28
Server: Werkzeug/0.15.0 Python/3.6.8
Date: Sun, 01 Aug 2021 10:35:43 GMT
```